# Missing progress dots on tests - Rails 3.2 + Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, ruby-2.0

I have an interesting issue. When I run the tests of a Rails 3.2 project under Ruby 2.0 (RVM) - the progress dots are missing. Everything else is OK - e.g. final report, timing of tests, failed tests info.

If I just switch the ruby to 1.9.3 - the progress dots are shown as expected.

Any ideas why this is happening or somebody who has experienced and fixed that?

Thanks!

Comment: That's funny, just run into the same issue. It's not Rails related because my project uses no rails. I think it's some kind of minitest's bug...

Answer (score 2):

I just solved this by replacing

`Test::Unit::TestCase` with `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`

and

`require 'test/unit'` with `require 'minitest/autorun'`

in my tests. Now both ruby versions are all green with dots! :)

Notice however that this is incompatible with ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Thank you, I will test that in a while and report back here :)

Comment: OK, I just had the time to review this again. Sorry for the delay! My project is using "ActiveSupport::TestCase" and not "Test::Unit::TestCase", so maybe it is not the case.

Comment: Too bad... :( So this might actually be rails related. Sorry I can't be of more help!